# mkfifo() not creating file in C

Tags: c, named-pipes, mkfifo

I'm trying to create a named pipe in C, but have not had any success.

Here is my code:

```
pid_t pid = getpid() ;
char * pipeNameo = malloc( sizeof(char) * 100 ) ;
len = 0 ;

//len += sprintf( pipeNameo + len, "%s", "/Users/Davidb/Desktop/") ; // tried various paths
len += sprintf( pipeNameo + len, "%ld", (long)pid) ;
len += sprintf( pipeNameo + len, "%s", "_") ;
len += sprintf( pipeNameo + len, "%d", i) ; // it is in a loop, i starts at 0 and increments
len += sprintf( pipeNameo + len, "%s", "o") ;

printf("pipeNameo : %s\n", pipeNameo ) ;
val = mkfifo(pipeNameo, 0666) ;
printf("Did named pipe succeed: %d\n", val) ;
```

So after running this, I check the directory, and there is no file being made. 
Here is some sample output:

```
OUTPUT, when loop runs twice
pipeNameo : /Users/Davidb/Desktop/1152_0o
Did named pipe succeed: 0
pipeNameo : /Users/Davidb/Desktop/1152_1o
Did named pipe succeed: 0
```

Please help :)

**UPDATE**
Ok I see that the ls -l worked for when the path was set to my Desktop! But it doesn't work when I try and set it to the current directory (where the main.c is stored). I tried adding "/." and "/" before the pipe Name, neither worked.

Comment: Does it work from the command line?

Comment: mkfifo() returned 0, which means it succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

`mkfifo()` will create the Named pipe for Inter process communication in the name what you are giving in `pipeNameo`. Named pipes are created in hard disk for IPC mechanism.

In Command line give `ls -l` to view that file.

For more reference [mkfifo()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo)

Comment: But the fifo should be visible in the file system (otherwise other processes could not open it).

Comment: @MartinR but Is it visible normally like other files?

Comment: Yes it is, if you are calling `ls -l` the first flag will be shown as 'p': `prw-r--r-- 1 leo abkdev    0 2014-07-21 19:32 fifo`

Comment: Ok I see that the ls -l worked for when the path was set to my Desktop! But it doesn't work when I try and set it to the current directory (where the main.c is stored). I tried adding "/." and "/" before the pipe Name, neither worked.

Comment: @DavidBaez did you try it without giving path? i mean only the name! In this case i think it will create pipe in your PWD.